# How to use BlobStorage for Azure Web App Diagnostics logs (using SDK)

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage, diagnostics, azure-diagnostics

I'm deploying an Azure Web App using the **Microsoft.Azure.Management.Websites** SDK.

I can create the web app fine with WebSiteManagementClient.Sites.**CreateOrUpdateSite**(). However one element that I can't seem to configure is the Diagnostics logging.

In the new Azure Portal, I can open "Diagnostics logs" and define both the "Application Logging" and "Web server logging" to use Blob storage.

I'm unable to see any options in the SDK libraries for configuring this - anyone have any ideas? I'm open to using ARM Templates if need be.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Joel, will you accept the ARM template solution for this as answer? I am not sure about how to achieve this with Azure SDK but am sure with ARM template.

Comment: @juvchan Absolutely, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved : The method WebSiteManagementClient.Sites.**UpdateSiteLogsConfig()** is where the diagnostics get defined

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can also configure the diagnostic logs to enable the use of blob storage for logging for web app with the ARM template section below.

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
  "name": "[parameters('webapp_name')]",
  "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
  "location": "Southeast Asia",
  "properties": {
    "name": "[parameters('webapp_name')]",
    "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', parameters('serverfarms_name'))]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "logs",
      "type": "config",
      "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('webapp_name'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "applicationLogs": {
          "fileSystem": {
            "level": "Off"
          },
          "azureTableStorage": {
            "level": "Off",
            "sasUrl": null
          },
          "azureBlobStorage": {
            "level": "Verbose",
            "sasUrl": "yourBlobStorageSasUrl",
            "retentionInDays": null
          },
          "httpLogs": {
            "fileSystem": {
              "retentionInMb": 35,
              "retentionInDays": null,
              "enabled": false
            },
            "azureBlobStorage": {
              "sasUrl": "yourBlobStorageSasUrl",
              "retentionInDays": null,
              "enabled": true
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "dependsOn": [
    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', parameters('serverfarms_name'))]"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this - I resolved it using the SDK methods, but will keep the ARM template in mind for future